# Quickest way to check if ip address is alive

Tags: networking, ip, ping, isalive

What is the fastest/quickest way to check if an ip address is alive or not?

EDIT
It is in a local LAN. It would be used to check for example if the ip is assigned to a network printer. And this would also have to be able to be down from code, preferably c#.

Comment: There is no sure way to do this. You could ping, but it might be blocked.

Comment: If the target IP address is  still under your control, you can create certain protocol of handshaking between the source and the target.

Comment: I have a solution with IcmpSendEcho(), but it's really slow if the host is not reachable. Btw I also need a faster approach in C++!

Comment: Also look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35580675/fastest-way-to-ping-local-network-addresses