# Fastest way to ping local network addresses

Tags: c++, winapi

I have to check several local network addresses if they are reachable or not. Currently I use `IcmpSendEcho()`, but it takes a long time to ping if the host is not connected.

So I need the fastest way to ping a local network IP, to decide if it's reachable or not?

Comment: Send out the requests in batches, and use an internal timeout. If a reply arrives after your own timeout then just ignore it.

Comment: What is your current timeout value?

Comment: If the host is not connected you're actually not able to ping at all. You mean timeout? The only way without that timeout would be to check if the interfaces are online without ping but using some other, internal method.

Comment: You might look at nmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really only one way to do this, which is the method you currently use. There are many different wrappers of ICMP, but ultimately, they will all end up performing the same network operation.

You have a couple of ways to speed things up:

1. Since you have several addresses to test, you can perform the tests in parallel using threads.
2. You can use a shorter timeout.